# Python for loop one-line difference from regullar

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I just came up with a difference between one line and regular for loop.

As an example;

```
obs = [6, 12, 8, 10, 20 16]
freq = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
data = []


data.extend(obs[i:i+1] * freq[i] for i in range(len(obs)))
```

outputs

```
[[6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [12, 12, 12, 12], [8, 8, 8], [10, 10], [20], [16, 16, 16, 16, 16]]
```

However,

```
for i in range(len(obs)):
    data.extend(obs[i:i+1] * freq[i])
```

outputs

```
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 12, 12, 12, 12, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 20, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16]
```

Can someone kindly explain what causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extend`ing x by y means appending each entry of y to x.

Since the entries of `obs[i:i+1] * freq[i] for i in range(len(obs))` are lists of integers, `data.extend(obs[i:i+1] * freq[i] for i in range(len(obs)))` will append of *lists of integers* to `data`, not integers.

On the other hand, the elements of `obs[i:i+1] * freq[i]` are integers, and therefore `data.extend(obs[i:i+1] * freq[i])` will append integers to `data`.

Answer (score 0):

This would generate the same output as the one-liner:

```
obs = [6, 12, 8, 10, 20, 16]
freq = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
data = []

for i in range(len(obs)):
    data.extend([obs[i:i+1] * freq[i]])
```

Comment: Explicitly extending by just a single value... if only there were a method for that :-P